# Invalid Handler Returned - PHP PDO SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am working on a PHP website that interacts with a SQL Server back-end. It works for maybe a single time and then when I try to log back in (which requires communication with the SQL database) I get this:

```
Fatal error: Invalid handle returned. in .... / sqlWorker.php on line 18
```

A connection string mistake might seem the most obvious culprit; however, as I said it does seem to connect once, and then break. What might the issue be? Thanks.

```
sqlWorker.php

    <?php
    class sqlWorker {
    var $user;
    var $pass;
    var $host;
    var $db;
    var $conn;

    function __construct($hostname, $dbName, $username, $password) {
    $this->db = $dbName;
    $this->host = $hostname;
    $this->user = $username;
    $this->pass = $password;
    }

    public function connect() {
    try { 
  // this is the "Fatal error" line   $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$this->host;Database=$this->db", $this->user, $this->pass); 
     $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Database connection failure: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $conn;
    }
```

The "login" logic

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
function formatInput($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = strip_tags($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

function alphabetizeResources($a, $b) {
        if ($a->name == $b->name) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->name < $b->name) ? -1 : 1;

    }
// define constants
define("HOST", "INSTANCE\INSTANCE");
define("DB", "DB");
define("USER", "USER");
define("PASS", "PASS");
define("ROOT", "/new/");
define("IMAGEPATH", ROOT . "includes/img");

define("STYLEPATH", ROOT . "includes/styles/");

define("SCRIPTPATH", ROOT . "includes/scripts/");


// necessary classes
include_once("sqlWorker.php");
include_once("imageManipulator.php");
include_once("entities.php");
include_once("cms.php");
// start session if it does not already exist
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}

$isTeam = strpos(parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH), "/teammember");
$isHotel = strpos(parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH), "/hotel");
$isAdmin = ( (isset($_SESSION['userLevel']) && $_SESSION['userLevel'] == 1) ? true : false );

// create instance of "helper" classes for database access and displaying HTML
$dbm = new sqlWorker(HOST, DB, USER, PASS);
$cmsInstance = new cms();

// user is attempting to login
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

    $error;
    $username = formatInput($_POST["user"]);
    $pass = formatInput($_POST["pass"]);

    if ($dbm->getUser($username, $pass) != false) {

        $_SESSION["userLevel"] = $dbm->getUser($username, $pass);

        if ($dbm->getUser($username, $pass) != 1) {
            header("Location: " . ROOT . "teammember/index.php");
        } else {
                 header("Location: " . ROOT . "teammember/index.php");
        }
    } else {
        $error = true;
    }

}
```

Thanks so much for any help.

Answer (score 2):

This happens most likely due to [connection pooling](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_pfe_blog/2013/10/08/connection-pooling-for-the-sql-server-dba/).

There were some issues with certain versions of the SQL Server drivers for PHP and connection pooling, so make sure that you use the [latest drivers](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/tree/PHP-7.0)

This should actually solve your problem. If it doesn't, you can **temporarily** disable connection pooling like this:

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$this->host;Database=$this->db;ConnectionPooling=0", $this->user, $this->pass);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the situation may be something like what simon mentioned.  I had never seen this problem before, but was able to work through it by restarting Apache.  I suspect this flushed all the connections it (the PDO driver) may have had open.